# Wamp stoped working after i installed Composer in-light me

Tags: php, composer-php, wamp

Sorry,

There is an error.

There is Wampserver path (c:/wamp64)
into Windows PATH environnement variable: (C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.35)

It seems that a PHP installation is declared in the environment variable PATH
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.35

Wampserver does not use, modify or require the PATH environment variable.
Using a PATH on Wampserver or PHP version
is detrimental to the proper functioning of Wampserver.

Press ENTER to continue...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your composer installation or another related installation registered the php PATH variable in your system. The Wampserver does not expect a php binary path in the system environment.

Try to delete the php path `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.35` from the PATH system variable.

Windows 10 and Windows 8

1. In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel) Click the Advanced system settings link.
2. Click Environment Variables.
3. In the section System Variables, find the PATH
   environment variable and select it. Click Edit.
4. In the Edit System Variable window, remove the path `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.35`. Click OK.
5. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.

After editing, try again. It will be better if you restart your computer before trying again, to make sure the system variable is not set.